# Trouble weight painting tongue

Tags: weight-painting

First character and keep hitting problems.
In Blender 2.79 I am using the Rigify_Cat armature and having trouble with the tongue.  For reference this tutorial is being referenced [at about the 39 minute mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_7a0b64Q5U&t=1732s).
For some reason I have not been able to figure out the tongue refuses to automatically weight to the tongue control bones.  No error message pops up but when I pick the mesh and go to Weight Mode it just shows as a black mass.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on or suggest a better method to connect the mesh to the controllers?

[BLEND FILE](https://we.tl/t-4dQM7eh96I)

Comment: could you please prepare a file with just the tongue + bones?

Comment: https://we.tl/t-69tcJosacX  Cut the file down as best I could.